# Spring security oauth2 http pattern not working

Tags: spring-security, oauth-2.0

I am having an issue where url patterns do not seem to be getting filtered in the security framework.  I have tried many different url patterns, jar versions, and configurations to no avail.  The token url works, and properly generates the token.  One potential issue is I have another filter (Wicket) mapped to the / path, so I'm not sure it that is conflicting.  I am using spring core 4.0.3, security 3.2.3 and oauth 1.0 (tried 2.0 as well).  Any ideas would be appreciated.

My configurations are below.

web.xml:

```xml
<servlet>
    <servlet-name>appServlet</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
    <init-param>
        <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
        <param-value>/WEB-INF/spring/appServlet/servlet-context.xml</param-value>
    </init-param>
    <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
</servlet>

<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>appServlet</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>

<!-- Spring Security Filter for all Requests -->
<filter>
    <filter-name>springSecurityFilterChain</filter-name>
    <filter-class>org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy</filter-class>
</filter>
<filter-mapping>
    <filter-name>springSecurityFilterChain</filter-name>
    <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
</filter-mapping>

<filter>
    <filter-name>MyCC</filter-name>
    <filter-class>org.apache.wicket.protocol.http.WicketFilter</filter-class>
    <init-param>
        <param-name>applicationClassName</param-name>
        <param-value>com.wth.mycc.Wicket.Application.MyCCApplication</param-value>
    </init-param>
</filter>

<filter-mapping>
    <filter-name>MyCC</filter-name>
    <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
    <dispatcher>REQUEST</dispatcher>
    <dispatcher>ERROR</dispatcher>
</filter-mapping>
```

spring bean mapping xml config file:

```xml
<!-- Security Config -->
<http pattern="/oauth/token" create-session="stateless"
    authentication-manager-ref="authenticationManager"
    xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/security">
    <intercept-url pattern="/oauth/token" access="IS_AUTHENTICATED_FULLY" />
    <anonymous enabled="false" />
    <http-basic entry-point-ref="clientAuthenticationEntryPoint" />
    <custom-filter ref="clientCredentialsTokenEndpointFilter"
        before="BASIC_AUTH_FILTER" />
    <access-denied-handler ref="oauthAccessDeniedHandler" />
</http>

<http pattern="/rest/**" create-session="never" 
    entry-point-ref="oauthAuthenticationEntryPoint" xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/security">
    <anonymous enabled="false" />
    <intercept-url pattern="/getports" method="GET" />
    <custom-filter ref="resourceServerFilter" before="PRE_AUTH_FILTER" />
    <access-denied-handler ref="oauthAccessDeniedHandler" />
</http>

<http pattern="/logout" create-session="never"
    entry-point-ref="oauthAuthenticationEntryPoint" xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/security">
    <anonymous enabled="false" />
    <intercept-url pattern="/logout" method="GET" />
    <logout invalidate-session="true" logout-url="/logout"
        success-handler-ref="logoutSuccessHandler" />
    <custom-filter ref="resourceServerFilter" before="PRE_AUTH_FILTER" />
    <access-denied-handler ref="oauthAccessDeniedHandler" />
</http>



<bean id="logoutSuccessHandler" class="com.wth.services.auth.service.impl.LogoutImpl">
    <property name="tokenstore" ref="tokenStore"></property>
</bean>

<bean id="oauthAuthenticationEntryPoint"
    class="org.springframework.security.oauth2.provider.error.OAuth2AuthenticationEntryPoint">
</bean>

<bean id="clientAuthenticationEntryPoint"
    class="org.springframework.security.oauth2.provider.error.OAuth2AuthenticationEntryPoint">
    <property name="realmName" value="springsec/client" />
    <property name="typeName" value="Basic" />
</bean>

<bean id="oauthAccessDeniedHandler"
    class="org.springframework.security.oauth2.provider.error.OAuth2AccessDeniedHandler">
</bean>

<bean id="clientCredentialsTokenEndpointFilter"
    class="org.springframework.security.oauth2.provider.client.ClientCredentialsTokenEndpointFilter">
    <property name="authenticationManager" ref="authenticationManager" />
</bean>

<authentication-manager alias="authenticationManager"
    xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/security">
    <authentication-provider user-service-ref="clientDetailsUserService" />
</authentication-manager>

<bean id="clientDetailsUserService"
    class="org.springframework.security.oauth2.provider.client.ClientDetailsUserDetailsService">
    <constructor-arg ref="clientDetails" />
</bean>

<bean id="clientDetails"
    class="com.wth.services.auth.service.impl.ClientDetailsServiceImpl" />

<authentication-manager id="userAuthenticationManager"
    xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/security">
    <authentication-provider ref="customUserAuthenticationProvider">
    </authentication-provider>
</authentication-manager>

<bean id="customUserAuthenticationProvider"
    class="com.wth.services.auth.service.impl.CustomAuthenticationProvider">
</bean>

<oauth:authorization-server
    client-details-service-ref="clientDetails" token-services-ref="tokenServices">
    <oauth:authorization-code />
    <oauth:implicit />
    <oauth:refresh-token />
    <oauth:client-credentials />
    <oauth:password authentication-manager-ref="userAuthenticationManager" />
</oauth:authorization-server>

<oauth:resource-server id="resourceServerFilter"
    resource-id="springsec" token-services-ref="tokenServices" />

<bean id="tokenStore"
    class="org.springframework.security.oauth2.provider.token.InMemoryTokenStore" />

<bean id="tokenServices"
    class="org.springframework.security.oauth2.provider.token.DefaultTokenServices">
    <property name="tokenStore" ref="tokenStore" />
    <property name="supportRefreshToken" value="true" />
    <property name="accessTokenValiditySeconds" value="300000"></property>
    <property name="clientDetailsService" ref="clientDetails" />
</bean>
```

Answer (score 0):

I have my Oauth2 configured like this:

```
<http pattern="/oauth/authorize" 
      create-session="stateless" 
      authentication-manager-ref="clientAuthenticationManager"
      xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/security">
    <intercept-url pattern="/oauth/token" access="ROLE_USER"/>
    <anonymous enabled="true" />
    (...)
</http>



<http pattern="/oauth/token" 
      create-session="stateless" 
      authentication-manager-ref="clientAuthenticationManager"
      xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/security">
    <intercept-url pattern="/oauth/token" access="IS_AUTHENTICATED_FULLY" />
    <anonymous enabled="false" />
    (...)
</http>
```

both should work well. I had a problem when trying to create another one and the solution was to create it like this:

```
<security:http pattern="/basic-auth/**" (...)
```

or

instead of:

```
<security:http auto-config="true" pattern="/basic-auth" (...)
```